# Renaming Column names and then creating a data frame using renamed column in R

Tags: r

I am having a dataset name noaaFilename which is having multiple columns, out of those columns I need to change name of 3 columns (Dat, HrMn, Slp) to (Date, Time, AtmosPressure) and then make a data frame of these 3 columns. I am trying to do this, but unable to get result with column values.

```
colnames(noaaFilename)

  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "Date"] <- "Date"
  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "HrMn"] <- "Time"
  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "Slp"] <- "AtmosPressure"

  noaaData <- data.frame("Date", "Time", "AtmosPressure")
```

Comment: If the existing column name is "Dat" then you need to make your indexing test `names(noaaFilename) == "Dat"`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick - Kindly help me with this, I  have made a fresh link for this problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248600/renaming-sub-column-names-and-then-creating-a-data-frame-using-renamed-column-in

Answer (score 0):

After changing the names you need to subset columns from the dataframe

```
noaaData <- noaaFilename[c('Date', 'Time', 'AtmosPressure')]
```

Comment: When I am trying to do that then I am getting <NA> in all columns, can you please write the complete code?

Comment: @ShashankShekhar There's no way to "write the complete code" if you have not provided complete data descrtiption. Use SO [edit] facilities to put the results of `str(noaaFilename)` in your question body.

Comment: @42 - Here is the fresh link for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248600/renaming-sub-column-names-and-then-creating-a-data-frame-using-renamed-column-in

Comment: You shoud not do that. You should respond to questions by editing your question. I have flagged this question for deletion, but please read "How to Post".