# Renaming Sub Column names and then creating a data frame using renamed column in R

Tags: r

I am having a tricky dataset[3922327258060dat.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPnWj.png) for which I have to create a function to read three columns. This dataset is having multiple columns, out of those columns I need to change name of 3 columns (Date, HrMn, Slp) to (Date, Time, AtmosPressure) and then make a data frame of these 3 columns. BUT the tricky thing is the columns has sub heading as those names(Date, HrMn, Slp) as when I am trying to write 
`colnames(noaaFilename)`
 it is giving me this result
`"Identification" "SLP"            "X3"`
I am trying to do this, but unable to get result with sub column names and values.

Please help me to create a data frame with three main columns with name "Date", "Time", "AtmosPressure"

```
noaaFilename <- read_table2("3922327258060dat.txt")

readNOAAData <- function(filename=noaaFilename) {

  colnames(noaaFilename)
  noaaFilename <- read_table2("3922327258060dat.txt")

  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "Date"] <- "Date"
  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "HrMn"] <- "Time"
  names(noaaFilename)[names(noaaFilename) == "Slp"] <- "AtmosPressure"

  noaaFiledf <- data.frame(Date, Time, AtmosPressure)

  noaaData <- subset(noaaFilename, Name == "ATLANTIC CITY", select = c("Date", "Time", "AtmosPressure"))

  ## Stop editing here
  return(noaaData)
}
```

Sorry as this comes too long

```
dput(head(noaaFilename, 20))
```

```
structure(list(Identification = c("Name", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", 
"ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", 
"ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", 
"ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC"), 
    SLP = c("USAF", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", 
    "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", 
    "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY"), X3 = c("NCDC", ",997270,99999,20121029,0000,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0100,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0200,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0300,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0400,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0500,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0600,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0700,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0800,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0900,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1000,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1100,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1200,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1300,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1400,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1500,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1600,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1700,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1800,4,FM-18,"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), problems = structure(list(row = 1:94, col = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), expected = c("3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns"), actual = c("11 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns"), file = c("'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'"
)), row.names = c(NA, -94L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)))
```

Comment: Images are a really bad way of posting data (or code). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(noaaFilename)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(noaaFilename, 20))`.

Comment: Also, try `read.table` with argument `skip = 1`.

Comment: Use skip=1 in the read.table function.

Comment: Ignore that. haha. I'm too slow (again).

Comment: @RuiBarradas I have added that dput(head(noaaFilename, 20)) output in the question description now.

Comment: @Edward Sure I will try that as well.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Can you now please help me with this, as I am unable to do it complete. I am stocked 
```
noaaFilename <- read.table("3922327258060dat.txt", header = TRUE, skip=1, sep = "\t")
```
I completed this but need help in renaming the column names and then data framing it 3 columns together.

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty is in the column headers not having commas between them.

There may be a way to import that dataset without editing it manually. If you can easily edit it, then I would do that. Open the text file, delete the first row, put commas in-between the column names in the now first row (previously the second row), save the file, and then try again without the `skip=1` argument.

If you can't edit the file, or need to do this many times, then there may be a solution to import the file without the need to edit it.

Alternatively, since it looks like a fixed width file, you can try using the `read.fwf` function.

**Edit**: Or skip the first two rows since the headers are separated by space while the data is separated by commas.

```
dat <- read.csv("3922327258060dat.txt", skip=2, header=FALSE) # Added header thanks to 42
dat3 <- dat[,c(4,5,9)]
names(dat3) <- c("Date","Time","AtmosPressure")
```

Comment: Ohh Thank you @Edward for that information, but I don't know how to make that ```read.fwf``` function .. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Did you read the help page?  The time consuming part is getting the `widths` argument to match the data. But you have to skip the commas. I think it's quicker to edit the file though.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do use widths to solve this?

Comment: How about skipping the first 2 rows and adding the column names in afterwards? Use `sep=","` and `skip=2`.

Comment: @Edward. Those columns do have names in row 2. You method would result in the first row of data being lost.

Comment: @42. I know. But they're not separated by commas. And the first row is not important. There's no other solution unless the user edits the file manually. ☺ and the other answer is practically the same as mine.

Comment: Twice I have erred. But the names are there. And the first data line would become column names in your proposed method. The right way to do this would be to read the second line with read.table or scan and then read the rest with read.table( ..., sep=",")

Comment: Yes, the names are there. But they have no separator. The data are separated by a comma. Make a small text file like the OP's and try to read it in using your solution. Let me know the result.

Comment: Done. I've attached teh sample file to the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a single line that should be skipped followed by a header that has no commas and then a body of data that is comma separated. Here is an alternate approach that uses the `scan` function to pull in the column names that are separated by whitespace. (It did require adding an additional value to the 'col.names' to account for the trailing commas in each of the data lines.):

```
input <- read.table( "~/CSV3.txt", sep=",", skip=2,
                      col.names=scan("~/CSV3.txt", what="", sep="", skip=1,n=11))
Read 11 items
#-------------------
input
                        Name   USAF  NCDC     Date HrMn I  Type QCP   sip Q ATLANTIC
1 ATLANTIC CITY              997270 99999 20121029    0 4 FM-18  NA 999.9 1       NA
2 ATLANTIC CITY              997270 99999 20121029  200 4 FM-18  NA 999.2 1       NA
3 ATLANTIC CITY              997270 99999 20121029  300 4 FM-18  NA 998.3 1       NA
```

The default header argument for `read.table` is FALSE. The `scan` function requires a "what" argument to specify the column type. It can be given either as one of the defined types or as in this case by example, since `""` is a character value.

To allow the subsetting to proceed correctly the trailing spaces from the inluyt process of column 1 needs to be corrected. First notice the failure of the process at this point:

```
names(input)[c(5,9)] <- c("Time","AtmosPressure") # no need to fix "Date"

noaaData <- subset(input, Name == "ATLANTIC CITY", select = c("Date", "Time", "AtmosPressure"))
noaaData
#----------
[1] Date          Time          AtmosPressure
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The problem needs to be addressed by removing the trailing spaces from the first column using the `trimws` function (which takes care of both leading and trailing spaces or tabs):

```
input[[1]] <- trimws(input[[1]])
noaaData <- subset(input, Name == "ATLANTIC CITY", select = c("Date", "Time", "AtmosPressure"))
noaaData
#-----------------
      Date Time AtmosPressure
1 20121029    0         999.9
2 20121029  200         999.2
3 20121029  300         998.3
```

Success at last.

```
Sample text file
------------------
Identification                                                       SLP 
Name                       USAF    NCDC Date     HrMn I Type QCP   sip Q
ATLANTIC CITY             ,997270,99999,20121029,0000,4,FM-18, , 999.9,1,
ATLANTIC CITY             ,997270,99999,20121029,0200,4,FM-18, , 999.2,1,
ATLANTIC CITY             ,997270,99999,20121029,0300,4,FM-18, , 998.3,1,
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `read.csv` (wrapper to `read.table`) with *skip* (to avoid problematic, non-combat delimiter lines) and *col.names*  (for all columns) arguments:

```
noaaRaw <- read.csv('3922327258060dat.txt',
                    skip = 2,
                    header = FALSE,
                    col.names = c("Name", "USAF", "NCDC", 
                                  "Date", "Time", "I", 
                                  "Type", "QCP", "AtmosPressure", "Q")
           )

noaaData <- subset(noaaRaw, Name == "ATLANTIC CITY", 
                   select = c(Date, Time, AtmosPressure)
```

Comment: @Edward I'm not sure how anyone could "try". The data was presented as a png file. Are you using the dput stuff? Or are you working with an OCR program that converted from the png file?

Comment: @42. I created a small example file, similar to the one OP provided. No R function, afaik, will read in a text file if the headers and data are separated differently. If you know of one, please post a solution. If you didn't even try, how do you know using `skip=1` would work? Was it a guess?

Comment: skip=1 was a guess, just as your skip=2 was a guess. Further guess: You could read line 2 with scan, save the results, and then read lines 2+ with read.table and add back the column names using `col.names=`. If you correct your code below that I believe removes line 3 from your sample dataset, I'll be happy to reverse my downvote.

Comment: @ShashankShekhar, please advise if this solution worked on the file shown in your posted image. If not, please post text file content in body of question and [not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1422451).

Comment: @42. Thanks. I forgot to add to my solution header=FALSE in the read.csv function. This sometimes confuses me because the default for read.table is FALSE, unlike read.csv Why the R gurus did that baffles me! And my skip=2 was not a guess. As with all text files, you absolutely must look at it before importing it into R. Your solution keeps the original column names BUT the OP didn't want those column names anyway, they got renamed as requested, so it seems pointless to me. But nice work!