# While trying read.table() I am getting column names with .(dots) in between column names

Tags: r

How to get read rid of .. (dots) in between column names.

Using code:

```
noaaFilename <- read.table("3922327258060dat.txt", header = TRUE, skip=1, sep = "\t", dec = ".")
```

I am getting this:

```
colnames(noaaFilename)
```

```
"Name...........................USAF...NCDC..Date.....HrMn.I.Type..QCP..Slp....Q"
```

I wish to have only column names like Name, USAF, NCDC, ...Q

I have attached the structure of file along with the values below.

```
str(noaaFilename)
'data.frame':   93 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Name...........................USAF...NCDC..Date.....HrMn.I.Type..QCP..Slp....Q: Factor w/ 11 levels "0,1,","0,2,",..: 11 4 4 5 11 9 6 6 1 4 ...
```

```
dput(head(noaaFilename, 20))
```

```
structure(list(Identification = c("Name", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", 
"ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", 
"ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", 
"ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC", "ATLANTIC"), 
    SLP = c("USAF", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", 
    "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", 
    "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY", "CITY"), X3 = c("NCDC", ",997270,99999,20121029,0000,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0100,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0200,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0300,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0400,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0500,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0600,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0700,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,0800,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,0900,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1000,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1100,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1200,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1300,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1400,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1500,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1600,4,FM-18,", 
    ",997270,99999,20121029,1700,4,FM-18,", ",997270,99999,20121029,1800,4,FM-18,"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), problems = structure(list(row = 1:94, col = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), expected = c("3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns", 
"3 columns", "3 columns", "3 columns"), actual = c("11 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", "5 columns", 
"5 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns", 
"4 columns", "4 columns", "4 columns"), file = c("'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", 
"'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'", "'3922327258060dat.txt'"
)), row.names = c(NA, -94L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)))
```

I tried attaching all the structure of file and values above, I hope that now it will be easier to understand this problem. Can you please help me in solving this problem. It is bit lengthy but could figure out how I could have added less code here.  Please feel free to ask me for more information if you need. I may not be understanding what you are looking more , but incase if you need any more details I am ready to put it here again. ............................................ 
I have one more query at link below related to this problem.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248600/renaming-sub-column-names-and-then-creating-a-data-frame-using-renamed-column-in)
...........................................................................................

Help me with these problems.

Comment: Please show output of `str(noaaFilename)` in your edited post.

Comment: Please include the first 2-3 lines from the file `3922327258060dat.txt`.

Comment: I guess that the `sep` argument is incorrect.

Comment: @Edward what should be the sep ?

Comment: @Edward as this question was getting too long I am sharing you the link for complete problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248600/renaming-sub-column-names-and-then-creating-a-data-frame-using-renamed-column-in

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen here is the link to complete problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248600/renaming-sub-column-names-and-then-creating-a-data-frame-using-renamed-column-in

Comment: I need to see the data first!!

Comment: Linking to a previous question is not acceptable for opening a new one.  Also, your previous question is not properly groomed.

Comment: Oh. I see. The problem is that the headers are separated by space or tabs (\t) while the data appear to be separated by commas and perhaps spaces in a fixed width type ensemble. I've never seen that before. Hmmm...

Comment: @Edward I have attached all the data here in question by editing it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry for putting it insufficient information or irrelevant information, now I have tried putting more details by editing it. Can you please help me?

Comment: I think your sep should be comma not tab (\t), try using sep = ',' in read.table, or you can use data.table::fread command and which can guess [, \t | ; :] as default, if your separator falls in any of these chars, then you should get your data ready

Comment: @PKumar I tried doing that with sep = ',' but it doesn't work, can you help me with ```data.table::fread``` code for this ?

Comment: If you can edit the file, delete the first row and add commas between the column headers. Then use `read.csv("datafilename")`

Comment: data.table::fread not read, try using it , first you need to install the data.table in case you don't have it, then you just have to pass the filename with path, in fread parameter, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/fread

Comment: `fread` won't work (I think). Column headers must be separated in the same was as the data.

Comment: @PKumar Thank you so much this really works ```data.table::read```

Comment: @PKumar I am glad for your help. Can you please help with this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248600/renaming-sub-column-names-and-then-creating-a-data-frame-using-renamed-column-in/60249745#60249745

Comment: glad it helped, however on a side note if you don't know how to work with data.table, then use `data.table::setDF(your_data_table_name)` to convert it into data.frames

Comment: @PKumar Now I am trying to rename the column names and make a data frame of those columns in above link